# Monaco Editor | Is there a way to determine if the model value was changed programmatically or manually?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am using Monaco Editor for my angular project. I am changing the model of the editor manually - literally typing in the editor on the webpage, as well as programmatically adding or remove strings to the editor. I do this with the following commands:

```
this.editor.setValue(...);
```

or

```
this.editor.getModel().pushEditOperations(...)
```

I am detecting changes on the model value by subscribing to this

```
this.subsc = this.editor.getModel().onDidChangeContent((event: monaco.editor.IModelContentChangedEvent) => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

What I need to do is detect a new change on the model, and determine if the change was manual or programmatic in origin. The end goal is to disregard the programmatic changes.
The event emitted from a detected change is described here: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.IModelContentChangedEvent.html

I have considered encoding a boolean flag in the model change somehow, but this may not be possible.

I have explored the api docs for monaco editor and have found nothing that might solve my issue. Perhaps I've missed something. Here's the root for the API docs for reference
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/index.html

Comment: Note: i am aware of the editor property "onDidCompositionStart", this doesn't work because text can be added programmatically while manual text insertions are also occurring.

Comment: Update: I have opted to create a flag: isProgrammaticChange. This is set to true immediately before I execute programmatic changes and set to false immediately after. This has the effect of disregarding any new changes to the model during this small window. After this window, manual changes will again be considered. This solution has some margin for error but oh well. I suspect its the best I will get. Also, the margin for error seems so small that its entirely fine anyway

Comment: Why do you mean by "disregard programmatic changes"?
If it is about not adding them to undo/redo stack, there are some methods like [model.applyEdits](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ITextModel.html#applyEdits) that allow to change content without adding them to the stack.

Comment: The goal is to send manual (keyboard) changes to a server, but not send programmatic changes to the server (they just came from the server). I need to differential between edits that were made manually vs using model.pushEditOperations() / applyEdits() / executeEdits()

Here I am 2 years later looking into the same issue :)

Comment: Do you not have information on the source of the event within the event object itself? If not, do you have any way to add it? This would be more robust than the global isProgrammaticChange flag you suggested.